# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ALUMNOS

Tags: java, database, jpa

I am a student trying to build a simple web app using EJB and JPA in IntelliJ. Right now I'm just trying to print the list of "alumnos" contained in my mysql db. This is my EJB

```
@Stateless
public class AlumnosBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Alumnos> getAlumnos() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Alumnos a");
        List<Alumnos> resultList = query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

And my servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "ListAlumnos", value = "/ListAlumnos")
public class ListAlumnos extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private AlumnosBean alumnosBean;

    public void init() {
       
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Alumnos> alumnos = alumnosBean.getAlumnos();
        request.setAttribute("alumnos", alumnos);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/alumnos.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

class Alumnos

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alumnos", schema = "notasexample")
public class Alumnos {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Size(max = 25)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String nombre;

    @Size(max = 25)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nom_user", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String nomUser;

    @Size(max = 25)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nota", nullable = false)
    private Float nota;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "modulo", nullable = false)
    private Integer modulo;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNomUser() {
        return nomUser;
    }

    public void setNomUser(String nomUser) {
        this.nomUser = nomUser;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Float getNota() {
        return nota;
    }

    public void setNota(Float nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    public Integer getModulo() {
        return modulo;
    }

    public void setModulo(Integer modulo) {
        this.modulo = modulo;
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="CRUDWeb">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.car.crudweb.entities.Alumnos</class>
        <class>com.car.crudweb.entities.Historial</class>
        <class>com.car.crudweb.entities.Modulos</class>
        <class>com.car.crudweb.entities.Profesores</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/notasexample"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="none"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="notasexample"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I get a nested exception

> jakarta.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is:
> jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : could not prepare statement

root cause

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ALUMNOS

I do have a table called "alumnos" in my database and my persistence.xml file gives root access. I've granted all privileges to root.

I've also used the JPA console to execute the same query I'm using in the EJB and it works perfectly fine. It returns the alumnos contained in my db.

I don't know what's wrong. I've been searching online for similar problems but haven't found anything that works for me.

Comment: Hello, please share the code of entity class Alumnos.

Comment: Added the class to the post, thank you.

Comment: Entity class looks good. The table name is defined as 'alumnos' lowercase. I wonder why HSQL says in the error message 'ALUMNOS' uppercase. Maybe somewhere in persistence.xml this uppercase name is used?

Comment: No, there isn't any. Added it to the post as well, for reference.

Comment: Which user has created the table 'alumnos'? Was it 'root'? If not then use the same user for connection. Or grant permission to root user for access to your tables. And also - is any specific schema defined?

Comment: Yes, it's user root. I've just given all privileges to root for the schema I'm using but I keep getting the same exception.

Comment: OK. So the table is define in a schema. Please add schema as property hibernate.default_schema. Otherwise Hibernate uses the default - without schema.

Comment: This is being tough! I basically broke my project and had to redo everything. I've updated the code in my post. I noticed that I (previously) had 2 persistence units, and the name didn't match in my persistence.xml. I thought that fixing that would fix the problem, but I'm getting the same exception. Right now, I only have 1 persistence unit.  and I (think) I am using the correct name. I've also added the schema property as you said.

Comment: HQSLDB is case sensitive, so `ALUMNOS` doesn't equal to alumnos. All table names must be exactly the same as the name in `@Table` annotation. Please, check it.

Comment: My @Table annotation specifies name="alumnos" and my database table is "alumnos".

Comment: Using the same query in the JPA console works perfectly fine, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it.

I was missing the datasource for the persistence unit, so tomee (obviously, but not so obvious to me 2 days ago) wasn't being able to find it. So I added to the persistence unit properties in persistence.xml

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/dataresource</jta-data-source>
```

And added the datasource to tomee.xml in the conf folder of the tomee directory

```
<Resource id="jdbc/dataresource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
JdbcDriver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
JdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/notasexample
UserName = root
Password = 
JtaManaged = true
</Resource>
```

I also needed to add the mysql connector jar in the lib folder of the tomee directory.